# How to add multiple valuables with one key in python dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, zip

I have list of names and i'm trying to add them under key called 'name'.

```
list_of_names = ['john', 'lisa', 'david', 'frans']
key = ['name']
```

with:

```
namelist = [dict(zip(key, i)) for i in list_of_names]
```

code returns:

```
[{'name': 'j'}, {'name': 'l'}, {'name': 'd'}, {'name': 'f'}]
```

So, how to add whole name (not only the first letter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `zip()` here; just use a dict literal:

```
key = 'name'
namelist = [{key: i} for i in list_of_names]
```

or just use:

```
namelist = [{'name': i} for i in list_of_names]
```

The `zip()` loops over the two inputs to pair up each element; pairing up `['name']` with, say `john`, results in just *one* pairing, with the first character in the name. If you *have* to use `zip()` then at least put `i` in a list too:

```
namelist = [dict(zip(key, [i])) for i in list_of_names]
```